# "Are we required to attend any religious activity weekly?" Should the noun be singular or plural after "any”?

Tags: adverbs, word-order, determiners

Is the sentence below correct?

> "Are we required to attend any religious activity weekly?”

Is it correct to say “religious activity” or should it be plural, i.e. “religious activities”?

Answer (score 1):

**[activity](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/activity)** can be countable (when it describes a specific event or entertainment) or uncountable (when it means doing something). One could argue that religious activity could therefore be countable or uncountable.

> Are we required to attend any religious activity weekly?

The word **attend** suggests that we talking about events, so activity should really be plural: the sentence is not correct as it stands.

If, instead, the compound verb **engage in** were used, this would suggest that we are talking about doing something, so it would be possible to justify activity as singular. This [NGram graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=engage%20in%20religious%20activity%2C%20engage%20in%20religious%20activities&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cengage%20in%20religious%20activity%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cengage%20in%20religious%20activities%3B%2Cc0) shows that, even with **engage in**, the plural is more common.

Answer (score 0):

*Attend* can be used to distinguish the action from *participate in,* although it may imply participation or leave participation ambiguous. As Stuart F commented, there are subtle distinctions depending on the type of activity.

None of the definitions I have looked use the word *participate*. However,  when an activity is *regularly attended* it often seems reasonable to infer some degree of participation. In these cases you come close to the meaning of "attend school," where participation is assumed.

**attend**

> Be present at (an event, meeting, or function).
> Go regularly to (an
> educational, religious, social, or clinical institution) [Oxford](https://www.google.com/search?q=free%20dictionary&rlz=1C1CHBD_enUS911US911&oq=fre&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i57j35i39j0i67j0i67i457j69i60l3.1016j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#dobs=attend)

> Questions typically deal with your ability to do household chores,
> cook, shop, visit friends, **attend social activities**, and attend to
> finances. [ref](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Nolo_s_Guide_to_Social_Security_Disabili/_E7VDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22attend%20social%20activities%22&pg=PT130&printsec=frontcover).

> ...can assist community members into refocusing their attention to
> academic school activities by simply inviting them to **attend
> activities** like open house, strategic planning meeting and
> participation on various personnel selection committees. [ref](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Leadership_Problems/oadODAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22attend%20activities%22&pg=PT47&printsec=frontcover).

An *open house* is an interesting case, since by attending you are participating.

> ... so he cordially accepts invitations from Christian friends to
> **attend church activities**. [ref](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Hybrid_Tsinoys/HdbPDAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=I%20attended%20religious%20activities&pg=PT132&printsec=frontcover).

If you attend someone else's religious activity or service, you may not participate in all the rituals, but you would likely participate to some degree, e.g., standing and sitting when other do.

> We have stated that visitors move easily to **attend activities** that
> they like, and that CREATOUR activities can be attractive assets to
> territories. [ref](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Handbook_of_Research_on_Resident_and_Tou/ergIEAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22attend%20activities%20had%20fun&pg=PA277&printsec=frontcover).

> Patients with mild impairment may **attend activities** but do not
> participate fully or do not complete assigned tasks. Patients with more severe impairment **attend activities** only with staff encouragement or not at all. [ref](https://books.google.com/books?id=eHgesB1hVgkC&newbks=0&printsec=frontcover&pg=PA555&dq=%22attend%20activities%22&hl=en&source=newbks_fb#v=onepage&q=%22attend%20activities%22&f=false).

Comment: The OP asks whether the sentence is correct. Is it? In English do we normally say we attend a religious activity or service? Is "any" necessary or can we use "a" instead? What about the position of "weekly"? @Killing Time suggests that it goes before "religious"... so many possible improvements... and that's basically why proofreading requests should never be answered.

Comment: I'm still learning the ropes here. I thought the appropriateness of *attend* used for an activity was of interest, especially in light of comments by Rosie and Stuart.